# PHP - Verify if a program is running

Tags: php, linux, process, debian, open-source

I assembled and configured a mini server at home running Debian GNU/Linux with Apache. I also installed the open source video game [Teeworlds](https://www.teeworlds.com/) in order to run a dedicated server.

My idea is to display some information regarding the status of the server on my website, using Apache and PHP. The most important feature is to display if the server is running or not.

I tried using the **pgrep** command at first that works fine with many processes but not in my case:

```
<?php exec("pgrep process_name", $output, $return);
  if ($return == 0) {
    /*Service is running*/
  }
  else{
    /*Service is not running*/
  }
?>
```

Next I found out that this works in the terminal:

```
ps -ef | awk '$8=="/usr/games/teeworlds-server" {print $2}'
```

but I can't use it with the PHP exec command because this string uses double quotes (it doesn't work this single quotes).

Is there any other way to check the status of a process using PHP? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Note:** The game has been installed from the official Debian repositories.

Comment: Why can't you escape the double quotes in the exec argument?

Comment: @JamesHunt I actually forgot about that possibility! I feel so stupid! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JamesHunt the escape for the double quotes works: I printed the command as a string and the output is correct. But the both $output and $return are always the same, regardless of the actual state of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the **exec** command:

`exec("ps -ef | awk '$8==\"/usr/games/teeworlds-server\" {print $2}'", $output, $return)`

with **shell_exec**:

```
 $test= shell_exec("ps -ef | awk '$8==\"/usr/games/teeworlds-server\" {print $2}'");
 if ($test>0) {
   /*Server is running*/
 }
 else{
   /*Server is not running*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but mostly for restarting crashed servers. Teeworlds servers can reply for some incoming packets, for example, it tells server info for server browsers. So, if server sends response for our request, it's alive. I used this php function:

```
function is_alive($port) {
    $socket = stream_socket_client('udp://localhost:'.$port , $errno, $errstr, 3); 
    fwrite($socket, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x67\x69\x65\x33\x05");
    $response = fread($socket, 2048);
    return (!$errno && $response);
}
```

And simple example of usage:

```
$servers = array(); //you may have many servers with different ports
$servers[1] = 8302;
$servers[2] = 1234;
$servers[3] = 8308;
$servers[4] = 8000;

// checking every server
foreach ($servers as $servernumber => $port) {
    echo "checking server ".$servernumber." ...";
    if (!is_alive($port)) {
        echo " not running/responding ...";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

**P.S. Works for Teeworlds servers version 0.6.X**